# Samba - how to use domain users without a local user account

Tags: samba4

I have Samba 4 configured to authenticate domain users to my office's domain. (The Samba server is *not* a controller of any sort, just a file server). In my setup, I always use the `force user` and `force group` settings when defining a share, so that files always have the correct owner. Because of this, the users I'm sharing files with will never actually own any files on the server. (The few odd cases, I've already configured my `username map` to correctly handle.) Is there any way to set Samba up to allow me to do something like :

`valid users = localuser DOMAIN\domainuser`

without having to actually create an additional local user account for the `domainuser`?

Thanks,
Ricky